# How to invoke the “Print Pictures” application that comes with Windows 7 from .NET for multiple picture

Tags: c#

I'm making a C# application that creates .JPGs. I really like the system where you can select multiple pictures in Windows 7 and select Print. I would like to invoke that from my C# application in order to replicate the process. How can it be done for multiple pictures? I would rather not go through the lengthy process of creating my own dialogs when the functionality is already built into Windows 7.

this code is for one picture...

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "file_name.jpg";
p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
p.Start();
```

how about for multiple pictures?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i want " windows print image dialog " when select multiple pictures in " listview "...

Comment: Well, the only thing I know, is that your code is calling the context menuitem "Print" on images, which is by default calling `rundll32.exe shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"`
But this hides the window and prints directly, also multiple images are still not possible. I'm wondering, what explorer is calling when you select multiple images.